# solution verification solve the permutation equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, solution-verification, permutation-cycles

Definition 1.4.1: A permutation of a set  is a bijection (one-to-one and onto) : → .

Solve $\sigma x = \tau$ which means I need to solve it the following way:

$\sigma^1 \sigma x = \sigma^{-1} \tau \to I x = \sigma^{-1} \tau \to x = \sigma^{-1} \tau$

let $\sigma = (1,3,2)(4,5)$

which translates to:

$\sigma =$ 
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    3 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 4 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

let $\tau =(2,1,3)$

then

$\tau =$
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    3 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I am not looking to solve the equation in cycle notation until I get more comfortable with the material.

There fore $\sigma^{-1} =$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    2 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 4\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

so $\sigma^{-1} \tau=$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 4 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Are there any mistakes? Is it fine to do $\sigma^{-1} \tau$ rather than $\tau \sigma^{-1}$

when I multiplied back my value for $x$ with sigma I got $\tau$ back

Comment: Your result is correct.  Regarding your question toward the end, generally permutations do not commute.  In this case they do.

Comment: When do they not commute? If they don't commute then I must solve it as $\tau \times \sigma^{-1}$ i.e. in order?

Comment: If you can represent your permutation as product of disjoint cycles.  i.e. $\sigma = ab$ then permutations of the form $\tau = a^nb^m$ will commute.